# JBPM quick 10 minute setup issues

Tags: jbpm

I am JBPM newbie, have to setup JBPM quickly for a demo. We are trying the demo setup as explained in JBPM document [JBPM demo setup](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_demo_setup) . Looks like a simple setup, but when we deploy we get the error (see attached screenshot) . Tried this with 7.2 as well as 7.3.  Any pointers ?

[image]

Comment: any exception in log file ? share complete stacktrace